# Error when checking expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions but got array with shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

[Here is the screenshot of the error i have added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN9Jo.png) I am using my trained model using tensorflow and keras in react native expo-cli. I have to input image to predict emotions. My input size is (48,48,1). When i use jpeg image to decode in tensor, and reshape it, i get error Error when checking expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions but got array with shape. My react code is

```
const imageTensor = decodeJpeg(imageData).resizeBilinear([48,48]).reshape([48,48,3])

function decodeJpeg(rawImageData){
//Function to convert jpeg image to tensors
const TO_UINT8ARRAY = true;
const { width, height, data } = jpeg.decode(rawImageData, TO_UINT8ARRAY);
// Drop the alpha channel info for mobilenet
const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 3);
let offset = 0; // offset into original data
for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 3) {
  buffer[i] = data[offset];
  buffer[i + 1] = data[offset + 1];
  buffer[i + 2] = data[offset + 2];
  offset += 4;
}
return tf.tensor3d(buffer, [height, width,3]);
}
```

The ssue because of batch size, that it's giving unhandled promise rejection, conv2d_input expected 4 dimensions but got [48,48,3]

```
x_train = np.array(x_train, 'float32')
y_train = np.array(y_train, 'float32')
x_test = np.array(x_test, 'float32')
y_test = np.array(y_test, 'float32')

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 48, 48, 1)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 48, 48, 1)
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
```

Here is further code where i have specified my input shape.

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(5,5),activation='relu',input_shape=(48,48,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5,5),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1024,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(classes,activation='softmax'))
```

In react native code i'm fetching an image and converting it to tensor3d so that it can be passed to predict my result. when image is decoded into tensor it has 3 dimensions (width,height,3) whatever height and width are i am resizing it to 48 so (48,48,3) but my conv2d_input has 4 dimensions (batch,width,height,channel), batch is all images or an image. so they seems to be incompatible. so the error occurs here while passing tensor(image decoded) to my predict function, it says conv2d_input has 4 dimensions.

Comment: please put the complete error trace as is in a code block in the question. Also, for the purpose of the Stack overflow guidelines, please remove the additional questions and ask only the main question to make the post more focused. You can always open additional questions which focus solely on other problems you are facing.

Comment: Edited according to guidelines

Comment: Hi, I don't see the error trace anywhere in your question. `i get error Error when checking expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions but got an array with shape` Please provide this error in full and where it is occurring. Until then this question remains incomplete

Comment: Hi, kindly review it, i have added at the end description to the error.

Comment: instead of the description, i am asking you to please provide the actual error. just copy paste the full text of the error and paste it

Comment: i have added image of error in the start of descirption

Comment: Conv2D expects input of shape 4D, modify the input_shape of all the images to fit to the expected shape. Instead of image add complete error traceback. Thanks!